# Resizable collectionview cells

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, user-experience

[image: I have an example of an CollectionView with resizable cells]

How i can create a collection view what will rezise the cells while they are comeing to center, like one in the image up there?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741161/swift-how-to-get-the-centre-cell-in-a-collectionview-and-resize-it-when-scrollin?rq=1

Comment: You should add some code to show what you currently have. Helpful bits would be how you are creating the collection view layout etc...

Comment: You can also use widely accepted library for this type of requirement.  https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift How to get the centre cell in a collectionView and resize it when scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741161/swift-how-to-get-the-centre-cell-in-a-collectionview-and-resize-it-when-scrollin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create custom `UICollectionViewLayout` where you calculate the cell attributes depending on their position relative to collection view's center. After that, you override layout's `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds:)` method:

```
override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

This method tells your collection view that it should invalidate its layout whenever its bounds change (i.e. scroll happens).

You might find [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel) helpful except you'll need to make your own scale calculations instead of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make that using UICollectionView Custom Layout.

**Tutorial:**
https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

Or you can go with a very famous library in GitHub

**iCaraousel:**
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel